# MPAndroidChart vertical values

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to delimit on vertical values between 13 and 14  not this is how it looks my linear chart, always starts on 0 as the starting limit, I want to be something around 13. Please see the image on the next link to see what I am talking about, I am attaching the piece of code for it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrFlQ.png)

```
LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart);

                    LineData data = new LineData(labels, dataset);
                    dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS); //
                    dataset.setDrawCubic(true);
                    dataset.setDrawFilled(true);

                    lineChart.setData(data);

                    lineChart.animateY(5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer about this, you can check it here

```
 LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart);

                    LineData data = new LineData(labels, dataset);
                    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setLabelCount(2, true);
                    lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
                    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(false);
                    lineChart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(false);
                    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(maxYval + 1);
                    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(minYval - 1);



                    dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS); //
                    dataset.setValueTextSize(10);
                    dataset.setDrawCubic(true);
                    dataset.setDrawFilled(true);

                    lineChart.setData(data);

                    lineChart.animateY(10);
```